# Accessing SharePoint's Managed Metadata TermSets Locally and Remotely

Tags: c#, server, web-services, client, sharepoint

I have written a small program which has 2 main classes :

- `ServerSideMMS`: This can access the SharePoint Managed Metadata Services, but only from the server which is running SharePoint
- `ClientSideMMS`: This can access the SharePoint Managed Metadata Services from any client machine

These can both be used to access MMS services and retrieve the data. In my case, I only need to grab the actual set of terms (which is the lowest level of metadata).

**Server**

```
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;

    namespace CallTaxonomyWebService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A class used for retrieving MMS data. This must be run on the server
        /// which is hosting the metadata.
        /// </summary>
        class ServerSideMMS
        {
            private const string ManagedMetadataService = "Managed Metadata Service";
            private TaxonomySession Taxonomy;
            private SPSite Site;

            /// <summary>
            /// The constructor assigns the given SPSite and the resulting TaxonomySession
            /// to some private fields. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="spSite"></param>
            public ServerSideMMS(string spSite)
            {
                Site = new SPSite(spSite);
                Taxonomy = new TaxonomySession(Site);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get all the terms which are stored in the given termset under the given group
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="groupName"></param>
            /// <param name="setName"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public TermCollection GetTermSet(string groupName, string setName)
            {
                var group = GetGroup(groupName);
                var termset = group.TermSets[setName];
                return termset.Terms;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns an MMS group of the given name
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="groupName"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public Group GetGroup(string groupName)
            {
                var Mms = Taxonomy.TermStores[ManagedMetadataService];
                return Mms.Groups[groupName];
            }
        }
    }
```

**Client**

I wasn't particularly happy with the outcome of this class. As you can see I had to split the `TermSet` retrieval into 2 classes, because I wasn't sure how to create and return an empty `TermCollection` object in case something wasn't found, so I resorted to just assigning this to a class field and returning it from the main `GetTermSet` method :

```
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;

    namespace CallTaxonomyWebService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A class used for retrieving MMS data. This can be run from a client machine.
        /// Because of the more complicated nature of these queryies (when compared to 
        /// the server-side calls), I have defined a few private fields to store
        /// return data. 
        /// 
        /// For more on what we can do with CSOM and MMS, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/dev and
        /// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904534.aspx. 
        /// </summary>
        class ClientSideMMS
        {
            private TaxonomySession Taxonomy;
            private ClientContext Context;
            private TermStore Store;
            private TermGroup Group;
            private TermCollection Collection;

            /// <summary>
            /// The constructor sets and validates the ClientContext before loading
            /// the required elements of each Store, Group, TermSet and Term. This can
            /// be amended if we every want to retrieve more data but for now I am 
            /// just getting the names of each. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="spSite"></param>
            public ClientSideMMS(string spSite)
            {
                Context = new ClientContext(spSite)
                    { AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default};
                Taxonomy = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(Context);
                Store = Taxonomy.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
                  Context.Load(Store,
                        store => store.Name,
                        store => store.Groups.Include(
                            group => group.Name,
                            group => group.TermSets.Include(
                                termSet => termSet.Name,
                                termSet => termSet.Terms.Include(
                                    term => term.Name)
                            )
                        )
                );
                Context.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This returns the private "Set" field after calling "LoadTermSet" (which assigns the 
            /// requested TermSet to Set)
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="groupName"></param>
            /// <param name="setName"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public TermCollection GetTermSet(string groupName, string setName)
            {
                LoadTermSet(groupName, setName);
                return Collection;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Iterate through each Group until we find the right one (Name = groupName). Then 
            /// find the correct TermSet in that group and assign the Set field to that value.
            /// 
            /// This is structured like this to avoid local "return" variables ... 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="groupName"></param>
            /// <param name="setName"></param>
            private void LoadTermSet(string groupName, string setName)
            {
                foreach (var group in Store.Groups)
                {
                    if (group.Name == groupName)
                    {
                        Group = group;

                        foreach (var set in group.TermSets)
                        {
                            if (set.Name == setName)
                            {
                                // I would much rather this function just return the Collection,
                                // but as I can't guaruntee that a collection will be found, this
                                // could cause an error, hence the private field ... 
                                Collection = set.Terms;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Calling the classes**

```
    using System.Linq;

    namespace CallTaxonomyWebService
    {
        static class Program
        {
            private const string site = @"http://mysharepointsite/";

            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var mms = new ClientSideMMS(site);
                var termcollection = mms.GetTermSet("People", "Department");
                var localTerms = termcollection.Select(term => term.Name).ToList();

                var remoteMms = new ServerSideMMS(site);
                var remoteCollection = remoteMms.GetTermSet("People", "Department");
                var remoteTerms = remoteCollection.Select(term => term.Name).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any feedback is much appreciated, particularly in relation to my use of a private field instead of a return type to try and avoid `NullRefernceException`s in the client side class.

For example, would it be better to try and initialise an empty return value inside the `LoadTermSet` method and just return that at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private TaxonomySession Taxonomy;
private SPSite Site;
```

These fields should be `readonly`. Also, private fields usually use camelCase, not PascalCase.

---

```
/// <param name="groupName"></param>
/// <param name="setName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

There is no reason to have empty documentation comments. Either fill them in with useful information, or remove them.

---

```
var Mms = Taxonomy.TermStores[ManagedMetadataService];
```

Local variables also usually use camelCase.

---

> As you can see I had to split the `TermSet` retrieval into 2 [methods], because I wasn't sure how to create and return an empty `TermCollection` object in case something wasn't found, so I resorted to just assigning this to a class field and returning it from the main `GetTermSet` method

This approach is wrong. If you call `GetTermSet` for the second time and nothing is found, **it will return the previous result**.

If you want to return `null` in the case when nothing is found (i.e. the outer loop completes without `return`ing), then just do that. There also isn't any reason to assign to the `Group` field, or even to have it.

```
public TermCollection GetTermSet(string groupName, string setName)
{
    foreach (var group in store.Groups)
    {
        if (group.Name == groupName)
        {
            foreach (var set in group.TermSets)
            {
                if (set.Name == setName)
                {
                    return set.Terms;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or even better, use LINQ:

```
public TermCollection GetTermSet(string groupName, string setName)
{
    var query = from g in store.Groups
                where g.Name == groupName
                from set in g.TermSets
                where set.Name == setName
                select set.Terms;

    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```